# Laravel 5: show comments using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, fetch

I am creating blog commenting system, I want to show comments for a post using vue.js.
In console, it says

> Property or method "comment" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render.

Also, when I try to catch user name, I got this error

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined"
>
> I want to show comments and users who commented to a particular post

in show.blade.php.

web.php

```
Route::get('results/{post}', 'ResultsController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

ResultsController

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $recommended_posts = Post::latest()
                        ->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
                        ->where('category_id','=',$post->category_id)
                        ->where('id','!=',$post->id)
                        ->limit(7)
                        ->get();

    $posts['particular_post'] = $post;
    $posts['recommended_posts'] = $recommended_posts;

    //return $post->comments()->paginate(5);  it returns objects

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

Comments.vue

```
<div class="reply-comment" :v-for="comment in comments">
                 <div class="user-comment" >
                    <div class="user">
                        <!--<img src="" alt="" >-->
                        <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="30" ></avatar>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-name">
                        <span class="comment-name">{{ comment.user.name }}</span>
                        <p> {{ comment.body }} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reply">
                    <div class="seemorecomments">
                        <a href="">see more</a>
                    </div>
                    <button class="reply-button">
                        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>


<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
export default {
    props: ['post'],
    components: {
        Avatar
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchComments()
    },
    data: () => ({
        comments: {
            data: []
        }
    }),
    methods: {
        fetchComments() {
            axios.get(`/results/${this.post.id}`).then(({ data }) => {
                this.comments = data
            })
        }
    }
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<comments-component :post="{{ $posts['particular_post']->comments }}"></comments-component>
```

migration table

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('comment_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

comment.php, I have this.

```
protected $with = ['user'];
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if your ResultsController@show returns the desired data?

Comment: I did, I put return $post->comments()->paginate(5); in controller, then I could see 5 objects.

Comment: console.log the `data` object in your api callback and check the `data` object. I think it would be  this.comments = data.data. (check first your data object )

Comment: you're using the same endpoint to show the view and getting the comments. So when the `fetchComment()` method is called, your `ResultsController@show` is not returning a JSON but rather a HTML consisting your view. Try creating a dedicated endpoint that returns the comments for a certain post in JSON format.

Comment: @JulioMotol I added  a new endpoint Route::get('results/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@index'); and changed like this (`/results/${this.post.id}/comments`) but it didn't work.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu your controller must `return response($payload);` not a `view();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of minor issues with your Vue file that can be addressed pretty quickly.

First, you should define `comments` as an empty array — a collection will be returned as an array of objects to the Vue.  By adding an unnecessary `data` property in the beginning, you are allowing the `v-for` loop to run in your template before the data has been retrieved.

EDIT: I'm not sure about the way you wrote this data function, so I have re-written it a way in which I'm familiar.

```js
data() {
    return {
        comments: []
    }
},
```

Second, you want to get the correct data from the response.  Axios data is stored another level deep (`response.data`).  Of course, if you are paginating the results, they are one more level deep (`response.data.data`).

```js
fetchComments() {
    axios.get(`/results/${this.post.id}`).then(response => {
        this.comments = response.data

        // or for paginated results
        // this.comments = response.data.data
    })
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Thank you for providing the Gist! I think I'm seeing things more clearly now.

Update your controller like so:
*You want to load the comments into the post here.*

```php
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $recommended_posts = Post::latest()
                        ->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
                        ->where('category_id','=',$post->category_id)
                        ->where('id','!=',$post->id)
                        ->limit(7)
                        ->get();

    // load the post comments here
    $post->load('comments');
    $posts['particular_post'] = $post;
    $posts['recommended_posts'] = $recommended_posts;

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

And you blade like so:
*Your module wants a single post, not an array of comments.*

```php
<comments-component :post="{{ $posts['particular_post'] }}"></comments-component>
```

And you Vue like so:
*You don't actually need to use Axios at all since we've already loaded the comments.*

```php
<script>
    import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
    export default {
        props: ['post'],
        components: {
            Avatar
        },
        data() {
            return {
                comments: this.post.comments
            }
        },      
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still I have a same error. "comment" is not defined on the instance" .

Comment: I have put $post->comments()->with('user')->get(); in ResultsController but still, I have the same error. Cannot read property 'user' of undefined".

Comment: I see you have newly added `protected $with = ['user']` which should take care of the relation.  Are you sure all of your comments are assigned to a user? Can you post your updated code to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) including the Comment.php model?

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I uploaded my codes, if you need more, feel free to ask. https://gist.github.com/YoheiUmezu/6583a87933ed94ff7df28eb532819632

Comment: I have also tried adding a new endpoint . I am glad if you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217427/laravel-5-vue-js-property-or-method-comment-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-bu     .

Comment: Okay, I have some edits I will post shortly. I can see what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, please take your time, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry... I got errors again, but this time the errors are slightly different from yesterday one. If you are available, please  check it out my git. I uploaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200375/discussion-between-matticustard-and-yohei-umezu).

Comment: Just letting you know the solution is in the chat.  Tested and working.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I followed matticustardand, and I excluded :  from :v-for, it worked !

Comment: Sorry again I revised and I still have an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"....

Comment: Then you don't have a `user` in the database associated with the `comment`, because it works when all of the pieces are there.  If for some reason you want to have comments without users, you will need to surround the `user` section with `v-if="comment.user"` to check whether a user exits first.